# Servicestack.redis Transactions and Hashes

Tags: transactions, redis, servicestack

How can I get all the entries from a hash while in a transaction? I don't see an `onSuccessCallback` with the right type. I tried mapping it as a `byte[][]` thinking I could just manually deserialize it, but redis complains about that (*Operation against a key holding the wrong kind of value*)

Is there anyway to do this?

```
var hashValues
using (var trans = client.CreateTransaction())
{
    trans.QueueCommand(c => hashValues=c.GetAllEntriesFromHash("some key"));
    trans.Remove("some key");
    trans.Commit();
}

return hashValues;
```

So what I am trying to do is an atomic operation of getting all the values from the hash and then removing that hash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best way I could come up with is below. Based on [this from Redis](http://redis.io/commands/hgetall) it looks like the return from Redis is fieldname followed by it's value. ServiceStack.Redis takes care of the [dictionary mapping](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Redis/RedisClient_Hash.cs#L121) for you. In order to get everything to work within a transaction I think you have to work at the 'Redis' level.

```
byte[][] hashAll = null;

var client = new BasicRedisClientManager("localhost:6379");
using (var trans = client.GetClient().CreateTransaction())
{
    trans.QueueCommand(r => ((RedisNativeClient)r).HGetAll("meHashKey"), result => hashAll = result);         
    trans.QueueCommand(r => r.Remove("meHashKey"));
    trans.Commit();
}

//variable map will hold the Hash/Dictionary<string, string>/Key-Value Pairings
var map = new Dictionary<string, string>(); 
for (var i = 0; i < hashAll.Length; i += 2)
{
    var key = hashAll[i].FromUtf8Bytes();
    map[key] = hashAll[i + 1].FromUtf8Bytes();
}
```

Comment: I was trying to do just this, but I didn't think about casting to a `RedisNaticClient`. I'm going to try this out as soon as I get home. Thanks!